# Verifone VX675 accidentaly changed group pw to text

Tags: terminal, passwords, verifone

I used a script to assemble a loading file for the Verifone V675 terminal.
After I loaded the terminal with new applications I suddenly couldn't access the group 1 in terminal MNGR.

The default password is 11111
What happened is that I accidentally set the password using this line "*PW=11111setgroup.4" because I didn't break the line.

Does anyone have an idea what the password could translate to?

I tried 11111 and ASCII values of the "setgroup.4" characters but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. If there is any other way how to erase the terminal memory that would most likely also work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

If there is some password error. It rolls back to the default password which is **166831**